# Xpages get All documents more than one Lotus Database

Tags: datatable, xpages, repeat

I have 3 databases and the same named view on each of them. I just want to pull all documents from that 3 views in to a one dataTable or repeat control or any other component whichcan be used. 
I just want to gather all documents to see them on one screen.

Regards
C.A.

Comment: Just build a Java bean. Create a model which stores the values as fields you want to display and create a list of these objects in Java by getting data from all three databases, then display the Java list in the UI using a repeat control. That way you are looking at a Java object, rather than a domino view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Howard - you actually can't create a DocumentCollection that spans databases. I tried this recently and discovered so. Since I could return the values from each nsf in a different 'tab' (I'm using datatables in a tabbed panel), my search is done in a bean. I'm just returning the NoteID, then calling the doc values to populate my table.

@Cumhur, I'd suggest doing something similar, but you might need to add the source database.

I didn't need to go further than get the NoteIDs for my project, but I was having some difficulty if I tried to get values out of the object. My next step would have been to create a JSON array with the NoteID and source nsf. But I didn't go there. It might be a solution for you, however. Get the search results from each nsf and combine them and return the combined result.

Comment: I stand corrected on that first part of my reply, as I said, I would just use a Java bean to do this. It could also be done with SSJS but not what I would suggest...

Comment: I do not have enough java experience :( if you don't mind and if it's possible could you please send me a sample of your bean class? 
Because I do not know how to do it with java :(

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a standalone example I could send. As far as Java experience, we do offer Java courses for XPages at http://www.tlcc.com. Howard

Comment: I'm afraid it's a bit too work related for me to post. There are examples of turning a view entry collection into a JSON, just do that for each different database, adding each to the JSON. A JSON return of the database name and NoteID or UNID would give you access back to the correct document.

Answer (score 3):

In general the way to handle this issue with a `managed bean` is absolutely right, but keep in mind that if you have to deal with big data, it would be a performance problem, because the programmatic way (using java "data" objects, including operations such as sorting, filtering, etc.) is much more slower than to work with indexed data (e.g. `xp:dominoView`)!

*In my opinion you have only two choices:*

1) The programmatic way, with java (managed beans) or server side javascript.

2) The "indexed way", if it is possible to collect your data into one database (e.g. with a scheduled agent)

Answer (score 2):

You could get the documents and add them all to a DocumentCollection and pass that to a repeat (and probably a Data Table too).

What I would do is create a Java bean that gets the documents. Inside that bean you have a public class, lets say we call it docInfo. That class has the data for each row in it (name, address, whatever) and probably the docId in case you want to allow opening the document. When you create a new instance of that docInfo class and add it to a List. Then have a method that returns the List. This is what you will call in your repeat and then use a getter to get the values for each row. If your var for the repeat is row, then you would use row.getName() to get the name, etc.

This would give you the flexibility to control the sorting and also have methods to filter your documents if desired.

Howard